# GCC 3.4.4 install while running GCC 4.7.3 with Cygwin

Tags: c, gcc

I have been looking at some old code that was compiled using GCC 3.4.4 but I currently run GCC 4.7.3 on cygwin. I'm still very much learning, so re-compiling this good is not an option as of yet. I am wondering if there is a simple, or somewhat simple way being able to install gcc 3.4.4 while running 4.7.3 so I can compile this code.

Comment: By default when you build and install from source, GCC will install itself in different directories and with different names of the executables.

Comment: I'm curious; have you attempted to compile the code with the updated compiler? It _might_ work.

Comment: Yah I tried, no dice.

Comment: Joachim, It's actually a mud haha

Comment: Just to note, built a VM using RHEL 6 and it had GCC 4.4 on it by default. After doing this, there was only one make error which I've since resolved and am running fine.